# Replacing/modifing the text selection method (long press, handles) in Android with a different one?

Tags: android, text

I have an idea how to enhance the text selection (long press on a word select it, with two handles you can correct the selection) on Android for an academic project. I don't see a problem with coding the logic from this enhancement, but as I'm new to the Android world I'm pretty lost how to integrate it into the OS. I'm very certain that I have hours of reading the API before me, but I wouldn't mind to lighten the jungle a bit. That's why I asking here.

In a nut shell:

I want to implement an own text selection gesture that should replace the current selection method (long press on a word select it, with two handles you can correct the selection) in the browser and PDF reader. Actually one can say if possible system wide. My first idea is to make an App that overrides the current behaviour.

- Is it possible to replace the current test selection mechanism system wide? In other words, is there a way to override the given text selection behaviour with an own App? Like you can change the keyboard with a different one(swipe keyboard, SwiftKey X, etc.). Or is it not possible to modify Android on such a low level with an App?
- Which packet or classes in Android are responsible for the text selection?

I'm very thankful for every hint on that topic.